# How to show labels with direction on google map api

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, label, google-maps-markers

I would like to show a label with a direction icon similar to the one shown in the picture (captured from default embedded iframe).

The following is my current code.

```
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);
    var lat = 25.2091043;
    var lng = 55.2725799;
    function init() {
        var mapOptions1 = {
            zoom: 18,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP               
        };
        var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
        '<div id="siteNotice">'+
        '</div>'+
        '<h2 class="title text-center" id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Your Header</h2>'+
        '<div class="text-center" id="bodyContent">'+
            '<p>Suite <b>4701-01, Aspin Commercial Tower, Sheikh Zayed Road, Dubai, United Arab Emirates</b></p>' +
            '<a href="https://maps.google.com/maps?ll=25.208963,55.272498&z=19&t=m&hl=en&gl=LK&mapclient=embed&daddr=Aspin%20Commercial%20Tower%20106%20Sheikh%20Zayed%20Rd%20Dubai%20United%20Arab%20Emirates@25.2089625,55.2724984" target="_blank">Get directions</a>'
        '</div>'+
        '</div>';

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: contentString
        });

        // Get all html elements for map
        var mapElement1 = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
        var map1 = new google.maps.Map(mapElement1, mapOptions1);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: { lat: lat, lng: lng },
            map: map1,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        });
        infowindow.open(map1, marker);
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image: Expected result]

[image: Current result]

Comment: What trouble are you having creating that?

Comment: Please see the updated code. I ended up with infowindow and changes reflected in image 2. However, I was wondering if there way to popup the native window similar to image 1 which was the expected result. please ignore the style differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to create that `<div>` as a [custom control](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#CustomControls), create the links for "View larger map" and "Directions" by sending the user to Google Maps.

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/35qwayo6/8/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);
var lat = 25.2091043;
var lng = 55.2725799;

function init() {
  var mapOptions1 = {
    zoom: 18,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    mapTypeControl: false
  };
  var mapElement1 = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
  var map1 = new google.maps.Map(mapElement1, mapOptions1);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {
      lat: lat,
      lng: lng
    },
    map: map1,
    icon: {
      url: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png",
      labelOrigin: new google.maps.Point(100, 32),
      size: new google.maps.Size(32, 32),
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(16, 32)
    },
    label: {
      text: "Aspin Commercial Tower",
      color: "#C70E20",
      fontWeight: "bold"
    }
  });
  var measle = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: marker.getPosition(),
    map: marker.getMap(),
    zIndex: 0,
    icon: {
      url: "https://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/markers2/measle.png",
      size: new google.maps.Size(7, 7),
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(4, 4)
    }
  });
  // Create the DIV to hold the control and call the CenterControl()
  // constructor passing in this DIV.
  var directionsControlDiv = document.createElement('div');
  var directionsControl = new DirectionsControl(directionsControlDiv, map1);

  directionsControlDiv.index = 1;
  map1.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(directionsControlDiv);
}

/**
 * The DirectionsControl adds a control to the map that gets directions
 * This constructor takes the control DIV as an argument.
 * @constructor
 */
function DirectionsControl(controlDiv, map) {

  // Set CSS for the control border.
  var controlUI = document.createElement('div');
  controlUI.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
  controlUI.style.border = '2px solid #fff';
  controlUI.style.borderRadius = '3px';
  controlUI.style.boxShadow = '0 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.3)';
  controlUI.style.cursor = 'pointer';
  controlUI.style.marginBottom = '22px';
  controlUI.style.textAlign = 'left';
  controlUI.style.marginTop = '10px';
  controlUI.style.marginLeft = '10px';
  controlUI.id = 'controlUI';
  controlDiv.appendChild(controlUI);

  // Set CSS for the control interior.
  var controlText = document.createElement('div');
  controlText.style.color = 'rgb(25,25,25)';
  controlText.style.fontFamily = 'Roboto,Arial,sans-serif';
  controlText.style.fontSize = '16px';
  controlText.style.lineHeight = '24px';
  controlText.style.paddingLeft = '5px';
  controlText.style.paddingRight = '5px';
  controlText.id = 'controlText';
  controlText.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
  controlText.innerHTML = '<div id="controlTextInner" class="cf" style="width:350px; height:auto; background-color: white; padding: 5px;"><div style="width:250px; height:auto; float: left;">Aspin Commercial Tower<br>106 Sheikh Zayed Rd - Dubai - United Arab Emirates<br><a href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/Aspin+Commercial+Tower+-+106+Sheikh+Zayed+Rd+-+Dubai+-+United+Arab+Emirates/@25.2089625,55.2703097,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x3e5f428853023db3:0x6e63a9fe6b2d7cfe!8m2!3d25.2089625!4d55.2724984" target="_top">view larger map</a></div><a href="https://www.google.com/maps/dir//Aspin+Commercial+Tower+-+106+Sheikh+Zayed+Rd+-+Dubai+-+United+Arab+Emirates/@25.2089625,55.2703097,17z/data=!4m9!4m8!1m0!1m5!1m1!1s0x3e5f428853023db3:0x6e63a9fe6b2d7cfe!2m2!1d55.2724984!2d25.2089625!3e0" target="_top"><img id="directions" align="right;" style="padding: 10px; vertical-align: top;" title="get directions" alt="get directions" src="data:image/png;base64,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"/></a><br></div>';
  controlUI.appendChild(controlText);

  // Setup the click event listeners: simply set the map to Chicago.
  controlUI.addEventListener('click', function() {
    map.setCenter(chicago);
  });

}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
 * element that contains the map. */

#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/* from http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/ */


/**
 * For modern browsers
 * 1. The space content is one way to avoid an Opera bug when the
 *    contenteditable attribute is included anywhere else in the document.
 *    Otherwise it causes space to appear at the top and bottom of elements
 *    that are clearfixed.
 * 2. The use of `table` rather than `block` is only necessary if using
 *    `:before` to contain the top-margins of child elements.
 */

.cf::before,
.cf::after {
  content: " ";
  /* 1 */
  display: table;
  /* 2 */
}

.cf::after {
  clear: both;
}


/**
 * For IE 6/7 only
 * Include this rule to trigger hasLayout and contain floats.
 */

.cf {
  *zoom: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
```