# Show Address On Google Maps Label And Add Business Name On Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

[image]

I am very new to Google MAPs API. I am trying to create a map for my business with that replicates the below picture. I have the code below as well where I have the lat and long coordinates, and a marker initiated based on those cordinates. How can i show something similar like this with javascript, where on page load

1. A label as below shows the name of the business and address, with also a clickable link (an arrow for directions, not shown in picture)
2. Custom html showing business name next to marker on maps

?

```
 <div id="map"></div>
 <script>
    function initMap() {
        // The location of UluruBBS
        var uluru = { lat: 33.931, lng:  -84.337732 };
        // The map, centered at Uluru
        var map = new google.maps.Map(
        document.getElementById('map'), { zoom: 15, center: uluru });
        // The marker, positioned at Uluru
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: uluru, map: map });
     }

 </script>
 <script async defer
                        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[mykey]&callback=initMap">
                </script>
```

Comment: If the business is already on google maps you should be able to just get the embed link from maps to put on your site

Comment: To get the red text, see: [Add marker with Google Maps Javascript API to look exactly as marker that were added in maps.google.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42165971/add-marker-with-google-maps-javascript-api-to-look-exactly-as-marker-that-were-a)

Comment: @geocodezip that is the solution for the inline text. Any idea now how to solve the label portion. I can't seem to find any helpful resource on the google maps documentation nor stack overflow.

Comment: duplicate of [How to show labels with direction on google map api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58815605/how-to-show-labels-with-direction-on-google-map-api)

Comment: @geocodezip that is a great link and an answer to this question. i also found another alternative by using google maps embedded api. Link posted  in the answer section.

Answer (score 0):

Found another alternative via google maps api docs - by using [Google Maps Embedded API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/start). Please refer to the doc for more information.